# Confusion about FFTW3 guru interface: 3 simultaneous complex FFTs

Tags: c++, fftw

I am trying to use the FFTW3 [guru interface](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Interface.html). However, the description in the documentation causes me more confusion that clarity. I want to create a plan for 3 scalar complex FFTs, each of length `n`, which should be aligned in memory one after the other (interleaved arrays). I do not understand whether this implies `rank == 3` or `howmany_rank == 3`. I also don't know, which values the arrays `fftw_iodim *dims` and `const fftw_iodim *howmany_dims` need to have.

While [this stackexchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938409/how-to-use-fftw-guru-interface) seems to have a good answer, it uses the same terminology of the documentation and does not "create an image in my head" of how the FFTs will be aligned in memory for different `rank`s and different `howmany_rank`s. That is, the answer does not help with what I am looking for.

For reference, this is the definition of the plan allocation function:

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_guru_dft(
      int rank, const fftw_iodim *dims,
      int howmany_rank, const fftw_iodim *howmany_dims,
      fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
      int sign, unsigned flags);
```

Note that using the "standard interface" is not possible since I have to switch to the `guru64` (64 bit) interface later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fftw_plan fftw_plan_guru_dft()` allows to define 1D-2D-3D-4D... DFT (`rank`=1,2,3,4... ) applied multiple times using starting points located on a 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D... grid (`howmany_rank`=1,2,3,4....

The argument `rank` specifies the number of dimensions on which the DFT is applied. The extends and layout of these dimensions are specified by argument `*dims`. After the DFT transform is executed, indexes of these dimensions correspond to frequencies. These arguments defines a multidimensional DFT to be applied.

Argument **`howmany_rank`** and **`howmany_dims`** specifies starting points to apply  multiple times the multidimensionnal transform defined above. Starting points can be located on a multidimensionnal array described by extends and strides. Argument **`howmany_rank`** describe the number of dimensions of the array of starting points.

Let's consider a field featuring 3 scalar components u, v, w sampled on a line at regularly spaced point of abscisse x_i=iL/N. The field is stored in memory as an interleaved contiguous 2D array of dimension (N,3):

```
u(x_0) v(x_0) w(x_0) u(x_1) v(x_1) w(x_1) u(x_2) v(x_2) w(x_2)... u(x_N-1) v(x_N-1) w(x_N-1)
```

A 1D DFT is to be performed on the space coordinate x. Hence, `rank` equals 1. Each 1D DFT is of length N, and the spacing (or stride) between two consecutive items (`u_(x_0)` and `u(x_1)`) is 3. Hence,  `dims[0].n=N`, `dims[0].is=3` and `dims[0].os=3` . `is` is for input stride and `os` is for output stride.

The 1D DFT is to be performed multiple times, once for each component. Since the starting points of these DFTs `u(x_0)`, `v(x_0)` and `w(x_0)` are regularly spaced, the positions of these starting points define an array of dimension 1. Hence `howmany_rank=1`. Moreover, since there are 3 contiguous starting points, the layout of the array of starting points is defined as `howmany_dims[0].n=3`, `howmany_dims[0].is=1` and `howmany_dims[0].os=1`.

The sample code provided in my answer to [How to use fftw Guru interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938409/how-to-use-fftw-guru-interface) (sorry that it did not help you!) can easily be adapted as:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<fftw3.h>

int main(void){

    fftw_plan p;
    unsigned long int N = 10;
    unsigned long int DOF = 3;
    fftw_complex *in=fftw_malloc(N*DOF*sizeof(fftw_complex));
    if(in==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    fftw_complex *out=fftw_malloc(N*DOF*sizeof(fftw_complex));
    if(out==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    unsigned int i;

    int rank=1;
    fftw_iodim64 *dims=malloc(rank*sizeof(fftw_iodim64));
    if(dims==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    dims[0].n=N;
    dims[0].is=DOF;
    dims[0].os=DOF;

    int howmany_rank=1;
    fftw_iodim64 *howmany_dims=malloc(howmany_rank*sizeof(fftw_iodim64));
    if(howmany_dims==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    howmany_dims[0].n=DOF;
    howmany_dims[0].is=1;
    howmany_dims[0].os=1;

    printf("sizeof fftw complex %ld\n",sizeof(fftw_complex));
    printf("sizeof fftw_iodim64 %ld\n",sizeof(fftw_iodim64));
    printf("creating the plan\n");
    p=fftw_plan_guru64_dft(rank, dims,howmany_rank, howmany_dims,in, out,FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    if (p==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"plan creation failed\n");exit(1);}
    printf("created the plan\n");

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                in[i*DOF]=30.+12.*sin(2*3.1415926535*i/((double)N));
                in[i*DOF+1]=42.0;
                in[i*DOF+2]=1.0;
    }

    fftw_execute(p);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("result: %d || %g %gI | %g %gI | %g %gI\n", i, creal(out[i*DOF]), cimag(out[i*DOF]),creal(out[i*DOF+1]), cimag(out[i*DOF+1]),creal(out[i*DOF+2]), cimag(out[i*DOF+2]));
    }


    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);

    free(dims);
    free(howmany_dims);

    return(0);
}
```

And compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm -Wall`.